# Использование подзапроса в выражении MERGE

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-merge

Хочу смержить таблицу с другой таблицей. Но один из столбцов мапится в таблице ключей и нужно использовать уже новые значения. Не получается использовать подзапрос.

Код сейчас такой:

```
MERGE INTO TABLE_2 ST
  USING (SELECT * 
           FROM TABLE_1 FT 
             LEFT JOIN KEY_TABLE ksubs 
                ON ksubs.PK_ID = ft.PK_ID) joined
  ON
       (ksubs.NEW_PK_ID = ST.PK_ID
    AND FT.COL_2 = <константа>)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET ST.COL_3 = FT.COL_3
```

Ошибка в:

```
FT.COL_2 = <константа>
```

> FT.COL_2 - недопустимый идентификатор (ORA-00904: invalid identifier).

Можно ли вообще в качестве источника для MERGE использовать подзапрос?

Comment: Вы поздапросу дали алиас `joined`. Используйте его, а не `FT`. То же самое про `ksubs`

Comment: Да, уже так сделал, но этого не достаточно. Со звездочкой не работало, запустилось только когда указал явно какие столбцы нужны в подзапросе и каждому дал уникальное имя. Сейчас выполняется (это надолго), но вроде бы запустилось.

Comment: Вы очень любите писать `select *.`, а я всегда считал это порочной практикой =)

Comment: И еще не понятно, зачем условие на FT.COL_2 с константой написано в фразе ON. Что если оптимизатор сам не догадается, что это условие можно начать выполнять уже в подзапросе до выполнения left join, запрос же может получиться в сотни раз более медленным, если там много записей и он начнет делать left join даже для тех записей, которые вы потом выбросите в ON

Comment: Запишем это в мои вредные привычки -.- Хотя, схема тестовая, поэтому с остальными значениями почти все записи вычищены, но обращу на это внимание.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, можно. Как источник в [выражении MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9017.htm#SQLRF01606) можно указать таблицу, представление или результат подзапроса.

> **USING Clause**
>   Use the USING clause to specify the source of the data to be updated or inserted. The source can be a table, view, or the result of a subquery.

Касательно ошибки в вопросе, в условии `ON` необходимо указывать алиас всего подзапроса, алиасы определённые внутри подзапроса здесь не видны.

```
create table source as 
    select rownum id, 'src '||rownum name from xmlTable ('1 to 3')
;
create table target as select * from source where 1=0; 
create view sview as select * from source;
```

Все три запроса действительны:

```
merge into target t using source s on (t.id = s.id)
when not matched then insert values (s.id, s.name)
;

merge into target t using sview s on (t.id = s.id)
when not matched then insert values (s.id, s.name)
;

merge into target t using (select * from source) s on (t.id = s.id)
when not matched then insert values (s.id, s.name)
;
```

и дадут один и тот же результат:

> 3 rows merged.